# Animation in Unity 2D not working as wanted

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I am making a 2D game in Unity and when trying to make the animations, it seems like everything is going wrong. When moving left, the character will have the running animation towards the right as if they were moonwalking. The jump does not work as expected..I want to add an attack animation too. How can I fix these 3 issues? Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public float jump;
    public Vector2 boxSize;
    private float movement;
    public Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    public float castDistance;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;
    bool grounded;
    public Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent <Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       movement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
       rigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(speed * movement, rigidBody.velocity.y);
       if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded())
       {
        rigidBody.AddForce(new Vector2(rigidBody.velocity.x, jump));
       }
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(movement));
    }
    

    public bool isGrounded()
    {
        if(Physics2D.BoxCast(transform.position, boxSize, 0, -transform.up, castDistance, groundLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position-transform.up * castDistance, boxSize); 
    }  
}
```

[IMAGE OF COMMAND ERRORS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQXIO.jpg)
[IMAGE OF CHARACTER RUNNING(TOWARDS THE LEFT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUSVB.jpg)[IMAGE OF ANIMATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIdxa.jpg)

I have tried removing the animations and starting again but I get the same problems. I don't have a lot of experience coding so I haven't changed anything since I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I can offer you some guidance

> IMAGE OF COMMAND ERRORS

This erros indicates that you have an animation called Run and you added an AnimationEvent called "AE_footsteps" to it, but the hero doesnt have any scripts with a function called "AE_footsteps". Maybe you named something wrong? Removed the component that had this function? Created the animation in a different gameObject and then moved to the hero, causing the miss match?

> When moving left, the character will have the running animation towards the right as if they were moonwalking

If your sprite is normally looking right, you have to flip it if you want to make it look left. You can add this to your `Update()` function:

```
...
if (movement > 0) transform.localScale = new Vector3(1,1,1);
if (movement < 0) transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,1,1);
```

> The jump does not work as expected..

Since you doesnt say what you expect of your jump, there is not much that I can say. The code seems ok, maybe you need to adjust your boxSize and castDistance values or you haven't setted the transition between "Any State" and "Jump" animations correctly (maybe the Transition Durantion under Setting in the inspector)

> I want to add an attack animation too

Seems like you already added an animation for attack. If you want to call it, add a parameter of type Trigger to your animator tree (the same way you added the Speed parameter, but just select Trigger and not Float). You can name this trigger parameter "Attack" and call it on your `Update()` code:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown("space") && isGrounded()) // If you press space and he is on the ground
{
    animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
}
```

Also, make a transition from "Any State" to your "Attack1" animation, where the condition is the "Attack" trigger parameter